# What a Contradiction?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

This contradiction, you must see,
please take a guess, what must I be?

To toss the outside, and keep the rest...
but keep the outside and toss the mess!

No strings attached, they are in your teeth,
What edible object must I be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

> corn

because

> you take off the husk of corn, eat the kernels, then throw away the cob.

Answer (score 11):

I can think of a few possibilities but... are you perhaps a

> Popsicle?
> I remove the wrap, eat all the icy goodness then trash the messy sticky stick.

Comment: While that is a technically valid answer, and on the right track, Desusovi got it.

Answer (score 1):

I understand an answer has already been marked as correct, but wouldn't the following make sense too, following the same reasoning as the marked answer?

> Avocado

Comment: Yes, that technically would fit the toss the outside, keep the inside, use the outside, toss the inside... but the rhyme indicates a mess being thrown away which a corn cob is more of one than an avocado.

Comment: Basically any food would work that has an outside (inedible) peel, flesh to be eaten and then a useless inner core or pit. Avocado came to my mind rather immediately, too. There are a few others.

Answer (score 0):

it can be

> a bottle of coke

explanation:

> open the cap and throw it away, and keep the full bottle, drink the coke and then trash the bottle.

Comment: Technically the inside would not be a mess (as per the rhyme) and you are not throwing out the outside in whole (I guess I did not technically specify the complete outside.)